# iOS app creates email...is there a way to not have a copy of it in the sent folder

Tags: ios, email

My app creates an email that can have sensitive data in it (depending on the users perspective).  Is there a way on the iphone's email client not save a copy in the Sent folder.

And in the same way, if the user choses they can send it via text..is there a way to not have it be in the Message streams.

I'm thinking there is not but I'd love confirmation of this if possible.  I've been scouring but can't seem to tell if it's possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll break this into two parts:

1. Not putting a copy of a sent message in the sent folder:

There's no easy way to do this since you don't have access to a user's mail. You could have the user enter their email service's IMAP details and write your own mail sending implementation that then goes and deletes the sent message from the server, but it's possible that mail clients would keep a local copy regardless of what happens on the server if they grab the message before you delete it. Regardless, this is a really terrible user experience (having the user enter IMAP details, not using the built in mail composer) and it'd be difficult to write (and you would need to be insanely careful about deleting something from a user's mailbox, and you'd have to ask them if it's okay to do so).

1. Not showing a text message in a Messages app conversation stream:

There's actually a way to do this. Text messages can be sent to users via a specially formatted email address that's different for every cell service provider. For example, to send a text to a Verizon subscriber it'd be 5551239876@vtext.com. For this solution to work you'd need to send the message using some sort of automatically generated email address that you retrieve from a mail server you've created, and then you'd need to implement your own SMTP mailer on the device. Of course, a user can always request text message transcripts from their cell service provider (and some have easy access online) and there's no way around that.

How sensitive is this information? Email and text message aren't very secure protocols. You may want to consider alternative methods that provide encryption and authentication mechanisms.

Comment: thanks. that's exactly what I was thinking.  it all depends on who the user is and how they view the data.  some would say not a big deal and others might say yes.  I'm going to post a warning and have the user decide what to do.  it's a feature they don't have to use but it's there as a "nicety". too complicated for the purpose.  thanks much!

Answer (score 0):

No its not possible if you are using the built in mailer in iOS. Something you could do if you wanted to get around this would be to make a customer mailer, send the information to a server and send off the mail through code but this is quite a bit more work.